# Is there a way to utilize both Section508 and WCAG2AA standards in a single execution of pa11y?

Tags: pa11y

I am attempting to determine if pa11y is the best tool to help us identify potential Section508 and WCAG2AA issues in our CI/CD pipeline. Thus, I am currently testing the single use version to view the results it generates.

The issue I am running into is a requirement of our client to be both Section 508 compliant and WCAG2AA compliant. To that end, I have determined to test 508, I need to set

```
standard: 'Section508'
```

The issue is, standard is a string and not an array value. Passing in 508 rules into rules when setting the standard to WCAG2AA doesn't seem to work either.

Ultimately, is there a way to run both without having to run it twice? I would like to return the results into one JSON file.

Sorry if this is a noob question -- my JS experience is limited, and my pa11y experience even moreso.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only use one standard at a time for each run.

That said, I don't recommend using the Section508 standard in Pa11y at all. [Section 508 was updated in January 2018](https://www.access-board.gov/guidelines-and-standards/communications-and-it/about-the-ict-refresh). The changes that were made to Section 508 at that time include the incorporation of WCAG 2.0, so if you test against WCAG 2.0, you're good for Section 508 too.

Pa11y relies on HTML_Codesniffer for its rulesets, and there's an issue in the HTML_Codesniffer repo right now discussing the situation; the conclusion of the issue is that the Section 508 ruleset is going to be removed in a following version as it's now obsolete. Once that happens, the ruleset will be removed from Pa11y too: 
 https://github.com/squizlabs/HTML_CodeSniffer/issues/202